# How can I promote this site offline?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I would like to help promote this site as an information-sharing resource among my local flying group. Are there any resources I can use to help do this? For example, a ready-designed poster or small fliers/cards to hand out.

If it helps the discussion: the audience I'm thinking of are (GA) private pilots, students, and instructors. I wouldn't expect most of them to have experience of another SE site, so building up the credibility of the site will be a challenge.

Comment: For now I dont see any resource available yet. However simply give them the site name and let them try it out would be a good start :)

Answer (score 1):

There used to be [Stack Exchange Swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86498/what-kind-of-stack-exchange-community-swag-do-you-want) and a [Stack Exchange store](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store) but that's gone by the wayside in recent years.

Really the most effective promotion for this site is Google and link-dropping in other forums. (Obviously we prefer *appropriate* link-dropping like "Oh they talked about this over on the Aviation Stack Exchange, the answers there might be interesting." over spammy "Hay ewe guise! Plz2Go here! KTHXBAI!" link-dropping.)

The site is also a good resource to give to student pilots or aspiring aviators around the airport as you noted, but we don't really have any premade promotional materials for that purpose.  You could certainly create your own though (a simple tear-off flyer can be banged out in Word, I think they even have templates for it now).

If you decide to create your own flyer [make sure to observe the Stack Exchange trademark guidance](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (which is really pretty common-sense stuff - you'd be hard-pressed to screw it up), you can post it here and we can ping the community team to get an eye cast over it if you want to be extra-sure.
(I bet others would probably want to make use of any promotional material you create too).